# Could not load type 'ProtocolSupportModule'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-modules

I've found a boss-level error that forced me to become an active member of stackoverflow.

I am hosting an MVC app and on root level it works, however css and images are failing. Even when going to the image directly via URL I get the following error:

> Could not load type 'ProtocolSupportModule'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Could not load type 'ProtocolSupportModule'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> ```
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load type 'ProtocolSupportModule'.]
>    System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase) +12510809
>    System.Web.Configuration.HandlerFactoryCache.GetTypeWithAssert(String type) +47
>    System.Web.Configuration.HandlerFactoryCache.GetHandlerType(String type) +18
>    System.Web.Configuration.HandlerFactoryCache..ctor(String type) +27
>    System.Web.HttpApplication.GetFactory(String type) +94
>    System.Web.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +375
>    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I figured this out. 
Under handler mappings, the OptionsVerbHandler was set to allow all verbs under the request restrictions section. I set it to only allow the OPTIONS verb and created extra handlers for POST and GET.

UPDATE:

> WHEN a GETHandler is specified on a folder with stylesheets or images the ProtocolSupportModule error occurs when the image/stylesheet is called. When no Gethandler is present on dll's views, the MVC app displays a verb rights error. 
>   I got around this by setting the handlers on folder level. This is a bad way of doing it. Are there any better ideas? I am sure the MVC framework should handle this automatically?